# ExecStart fails in systemd service for Golang webapp

Tags: go, ubuntu-18.04, systemd, systemctl

I'm new to golang and am trying to host a simple website on my server.

I'm on Ubuntu 18.04

My domain root directory is in `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com`

There I have a `main.go` file which is rendering a simple Hello World in the browser.

When I `go run main.go` from this directory, the webpage is working correctly.

Now I'm trying to create a service to keep the webpage available when I close my `shell`.

For that I created a new `service` called `golangweb.service` at `/etc/systemd/system`.

The content at that file is:

```
[Unit]
Description = Go Server

[Service]
ExecStart=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com
Type=simple
Restart=always
RestartSec=5

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

After saving the file I insert the folling commands in order:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable golangweb.service
sudo systemctl start golangweb.service
sudo systemctl status golangweb.service
```

When I try to get the status I get the following error (I xed out some data there):

```
 golangweb.service - Go Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/golangweb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabl
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri xx-xx-xx 23:43:52
  **Process: xx ExecStart=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com (code=exited, sta
 Main PID: xx (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)**

Mai xx xx:xx:xx xxxxx.xxxx.xxxx.systemd[1]: golangweb.service: Failed with re
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or u
lines 1-8/8 (END)
● golangweb.service - Go Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/golangweb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Fri xx-xx-xx xx:xx:xx CEST; 3s ago
  Process: xx ExecStart=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)
 Main PID: xx (code=exited, status=203/EXEC)

Mai xx xx:xx:xx xxxx.xx.xx xx[1]: golangweb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Warning: Journal has been rotated since unit was started. Log output is incomplete or unavailable.
```

does anybody know why this is happening?

Comment: From the tag: systemd questions should be for *programming questions* using systemd or its libraries. Questions about *configuring the daemon* (including writing unit files) are better directed to Unix & Linux: https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first argument to`ExecStart` needs to be an executable file. It looks like you've set it to a directory. If you were to try typing `/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com` at the shell prompt, you would see similar behavior: you can't run a directory.

You *could* set:

```
WorkingDirectory=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com
ExecStart=/usr/bin/go run main.go
```

Alternately, you could compile your code (`go build`), and then set `ExecStart` to the full path to the compiled binary:

```
ExecStart=/var/www/vhosts/mydomain.com/mydomain.com/compiledprogramname
```